# MySQL - How do I select from this table and sort by Date_Added?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table in MySQL where one of the columns is `date_added`.

For each `date_added` there may be several records.

I am required to show a webpage where it shows the rows sorted by date descending but at the most only 10 per date.

**Example Output:**

```
Jun 1
 item
 item
 item
 item
 item
 item
May 31
 item 
 item etc
```

Is there a way to run a query in MySQL which will fetch results like this?

Comment: ACtually I have not got anywhere . I was thinking of using GROUP but it does not solve the problem. I can sort it by date but how do I make sure that for each date only a max of 10 records are fetched

Comment: What is your table schema exactly? Please post in your question

Comment: which language are you using in your web application ? is it java or .NET or some other ? Please specify the coding language, may be we could help

Comment: Why somebody is downvoting? It's very serious question!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE date_added in (
    SELECT date_added FROM dates ORDER BY date_added DESC
    )
```

To the extent of my limited knowledge, you can't select just 10 rows for each date.  You'll need to enforce that limitation in the business logic of your app.

Comment: `ORDER BY`'s in subselects do not effect the order returned from a higher-level query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're after but you could try:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable GROUP BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: This would have worked fine, if each row had a different date value , but a lot of rows have exactly the same date value, so its not returning all the rows. For instance, we have 30 rows added on18th june, but it returns only 2 because of the hour and min value difference.

Comment: Will this limit the total results to 10 or results per `date_added` to 10? I suspect it does the former...

Comment: I think it will limit the total results to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done with a query, as far as I know. Only solution would be to put this logic into the code of the webpage.

Make sure the recordset is ordered by date.

In PHP, one option would be:

```
foreach ($rs as $row) 
{
    if ($tmp_date != $row->date_added) { $counter = 0; }

    if ($counter <= 10) {
         echo $row->yourinfo; //Whatever you want echoed from your recordset             
    }

    $counter++;
    $tmp_date = $row->date_added;
}
```

Comment: Yes, actually we already did that in code. Just wanted to know if there is an efficient way of doing it in mysql.

Comment: Well, if you find one, let me know! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about performance (probably not good):

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM 
    myTable AS m
WHERE m.id IN
        ( SELECT ms.id
          FROM myTable AS ms
          WHERE ms.date_added = m.date_added
          ORDER BY ms.something ASC           --- whatever (ASC or DESC)
          LIMIT 10
        )
ORDER BY m.date_added
       , m.something
```

You can also try this:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM myTable AS m1
  JOIN myTable AS m2
    ON m2.date_added = m1.date_added
    AND m2.id <= m1.id                 --- this could also be: 
                                       ---    m2.someField <= m1.someField
GROUP BY m1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 10
ORDER BY m.date_added
```

or the variation:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM myTable AS m1
  LEFT JOIN myTable AS m2
    ON m2.date_added = m1.date_added
    AND m2.id < m1.id              
GROUP BY m1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 10
ORDER BY m.date_added
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @rank:=0;
select TTT.f1, TTT.value
from 
(select TT.f1, TT.value,TT.c, 
@rank:=@rank+1 as rnk,  
case when @rank>=TT.c then @rank:=0 end as dummy
from (
select T.f1, T.value, cnt.c
from t2 T, (select f1, count(*) as c from t2 group by f1) cnt
where cnt.f1 = T.f1
order by T.f1 asc, T.value desc) TT ) TTT
where TTT.rnk<=10
```

where `f1` is 'date' field and `value` is 'item' field